# Replica input in HackerRank in another IDE (sublime text or spyder)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to replicate an input for a Hacker Rank problem into another IDE. Hell its not even working in HankerRank itself.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-lists/problem

Please help me by answering the following questions:

1. how do I access each line in the HackerRank platform
2. How do I replicate the input in an IDE like sublime text or spyder
3. Is it that my code is bad ?

Here is the input:

```
12
insert 0 5
insert 1 10
insert 0 6
print
remove 6
append 9
append 1
sort
print
pop
reverse
print
```

There are 2 challenges here. How do I iterate line by line
I have used the following code:

```
test = []
n = int(raw_input())
for _ in range(0,int(raw_input())):
    input = raw_input.split(" ")
    if len(input) == 3:
        eval("test.{0}({1},{2})".format(input[0],input[1],input[2]))
        print(test)
    elif len(line2) == 2:
        eval("test.{0}({1})".format(input[0],input[1]))
        print(test)
    elif len(line2) == 1:
        eval("{1}(test)".format(input[0](test)))
        print(test)

print(test)
```

The goal here is to iterate line by line and execute each line as a command.

```
Consider a list (list = []). You can perform the following commands:

insert i e: Insert integer  at position .
print: Print the list.
remove e: Delete the first occurrence of integer .
append e: Insert integer  at the end of the list.
sort: Sort the list.
pop: Pop the last element from the list.
reverse: Reverse the list.
Initialize your list and read in the value of  followed by  lines of commands where each command will be of the  types listed above. Iterate through each command in order and perform the corresponding operation on your list.
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a really good question about lists.
it can be solved with this approach.

```
N = int(input())
result = []
for n in range(N):
    x = input().split(" ")
    command = x[0]
    if command == 'append':
        result.append(int(x[1]))
    if command == 'print':
        print(result)
    if command == 'insert':
        result.insert(int(x[1]), int(x[2]))
    if command == 'reverse':
        result = result[::-1]
    if command == 'pop':
        result.pop()
    if command == 'sort':
        result = sorted(result)
    if command == 'remove':
        result.remove(int(x[1]))
```

coming to your questions
1-while taking input consider the values and perform the functions accordingly.
2-the code that I have given you will work everywhere (sublime,spyder etc).
3-I have some points in mind.

- you are taking input for 'N' and that is the number of operations why are you taking input again inside the 'for' loop.you can use 'N' there and avoid confusions.
- instead of checking the length of the input you can write the keywords provided like 'append','print' etc. and compare them which one is true and then act accordingly.
- 'line2' is not defined anywhere and at the same place in the 'if' condition you are using 'input' as a variable name.

I tried to explain it in the simplest word possible.
let me know if it helped.